# Write list of sample space's operations

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, math-operators

I'm pretty new to Latex, and I would like to copy in my notes this "table".
I have initially created a table, but, the result wasn't as good as the picture.
Can somebody help me to translate this image in Latex?
Thanks in advice!
[image]

This is what I've done so far:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Leggi Associative} & $E \cup F = F \cup E$\\
    & $E \cap F = F \cap E$\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Leggi } & $(E \cup F) \cup G = E \cup (F \cup G)$\\
    & $(E \cap F) \cap G = E \cap (F \cap G)$\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Leggi Distributive} & $E \cup (F \cap G) = (E \cup F) \cap (E \cup G)$\\
    & $E \cap (F \cup G) = (E \cap F) \cup (E \cap G)$\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Leggi di De Morgan} & $(E \cup F)^c = E^c \cap F^c$\\
    & $(E \cap F)^c = E^c \cup F^c$\\
    \hline    
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

You should consider that some of the picture's laws have not been written yet

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. What was wrong with your table-based approach? What kind of alignment would you expect instead?

Comment: @leandriis I've edited the post!

Comment: Is https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSRjw.png closer to the expected output?

Comment: This is not closer: this is exactly what i'm looking for :D !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the proposed typesetting is ugly because very unbalanced.

There is no reason for right aligning the labels, nor for moving them midway between the formulas (as you tried to do with `\multirow`).

There's no reason for aligning the equals signs, which are completely unrelated with each other (when in different groups).

A one time hack is needed for the last set of laws.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
% hack to get the alignment
\def\vemptyset{\ooalign{\hfil$\emptyset$\hfil\cr\phantom{$\Omega$}\cr}}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} ll @{} }
\toprule
Leggi associative & $E \cup F = F \cup E$\\
                  & $E \cap F = F \cap E$\\
\addlinespace
Leggi di assorbimento & $(E \cup F) \cup G = E \cup (F \cup G)$\\
                      & $(E \cap F) \cap G = E \cap (F \cap G)$\\
\addlinespace
Leggi distributive & $E \cup (F \cap G) = (E \cup F) \cap (E \cup G)$\\
                   & $E \cap (F \cup G) = (E \cap F) \cup (E \cap G)$\\
\addlinespace
Leggi di De Morgan & $(E \cup F)^c = E^c \cap F^c$\\
                   & $(E \cap F)^c = E^c \cup F^c$\\
\addlinespace
Leggi di identità & $E\cup\vemptyset=E$\\
                  & $E\cap\Omega=E$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on the context, you may want to remove the rules above and below. Capitalization is *not* used in Italian.

The hack can be realized in different ways.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inspiration!
I have to say that my aim was basically to learn how to do a "table" alignment like you did in the code.
I had taken the picture from my Probability and Statistics book as an example, and I admit that your version is very neat.

La ringrazio anche per la correzione relativamente all'uso del maiuscolo in italiano.
Devo ammettere che spesso lo uso di sproposito, ma è una questione mia mentale, mi aiuta in qualche modo a visualizzare meglio gli argomenti
Cordialmente Luca

Comment: @LukeTheWolf Making tables, or alignments in general, has no strict rules; judgment is required in virtually every case. One might opt for center alignment in the second column, for instance; in a case like this, ragged right seems to me the best choice. Opinions may differ, but I'd exclude alignment at the = signs, because it would suggest links or symmetries that do not exist.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  \text{Leggi Commutative}  & \qquad & E \cup F          &= F \cup E                   \\
                            &        & E \cap F          &= F \cap E                   \\[10pt]
  \text{Leggi Associative}  &        & (E \cup F) \cup G &= E \cup (F \cup G)          \\
                            &        & (E \cap F) \cap G &= E \cap (F \cap G)          \\[10pt]
  \text{Leggi Distributive} &        & E \cup (F \cap G) &= (E \cup F) \cap (E \cup G) \\
                            &        & E \cap (F \cup G) &= (E \cap F) \cup (E \cap G) \\[10pt]
  \text{Leggi di De Morgan} &        & (E \cup F)^c      &= E^c \cap F^c               \\
                            &        & (E \cap F)^c      &= E^c \cup F^c                \\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just to know: what does it change to put 2 or 3 in the brackets? @campa

Comment: `alignat` uses pairs of right and left aligned columns. The argument specfies how many pairs of columns the environment should use. Since I used a total of 4 columns here, 2 pairs are sufficient. (The initial 3 was just a typo.)